# Non-blocking synchronizers?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, nonblocking

Is there such thing as a "non-blocking lock" in Java? By that, I mean is there a way to retain the properties of synchronization (atomic protection and memory visibility - the latter can come later, BUT the first is the most important thing I'm looking for right now)  but also have multiple threads not have to wait for the monitor of the object?

What I'm looking for - just to be clear - is not CAS operations, but an implementation of, say, the `synchronized` keyword, or [`ReentrantLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) that works like a [`Semaphore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) **BUT** with actual synchronization semantics that doesn't block threads to perform a certain action like invocations getters and setters.

Comment: `synchronized` is meant to protect a critical section. If there is no critical section, don't use `synchronized`.

Comment: Your question embodies a contradiction in terms. If you want 'the properties of synchronization', blocking is one of them. Possibly you are looking for `volatile?`

Comment: @EJP re-read the question. I had the "but" bolded and capitalized for a reason :)

Comment: It's still a contradiction in terms. How is it going to 'protect code blocks' without blocking?

Comment: Except that I'm asking what you're talking about. You need to define what you mean by 'protected', 'safety in execution', etc.

Comment: @EJP synchronized semantics, but does not block, and used for code blocks, its all in the question. I am starting to think that this is not possible; as said by Biswajit_86.

Comment: It's all in the question except what it means. I don't know. That's why I'm asking. What does 'synchronized semantics without the blocking' mean? How is that going to 'protect' code blocks? When are you going to answer the questions being asked? Referring back to your original text isn't a sufficient response, for reasons you've been given.

Comment: The blocking is part of the semantics of synchronization.  You can't get rid of the blocking without changing the semantics of synchronization, by definition.

Comment: @WarrenDew Sorry for double post, but correct me if I'm wrong-synchronized makes operations atomic?

Comment: Operations being atomic means that race conditions between multiple threads are prevented.  Preventing race conditions means that only one thread can be allowed to proceed at a time; the other threads - that is, the other threads contending for the same resource - must be blocked.  That's what synchronization is.

Comment: @WarrenDew Atomicity is the full compound operation seen as a single operation, or no execution at all. Compound methods must block threads in order to preserve atomicity, which is what I don't want. So you are saying that you cannot preserve atomicity in a method invocation/code blocks in any way if you remove the blocking characteristic of  `synchronized` (if removing it was possible in the first place - how can we?)?

Comment: Basically yes, that's what I'm saying.  You can minimize the effects by using the techniques mentioned in the answers, but you can't get true atomicity in multithreaded execution without some kind of blocking lock.

Comment: @WarrenDew Hmm, thanks. I guess this isn't possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with the responses in all of the answers and OP, I conclude that this isn't possible with current synchronization techniques. I will conclude by saying that *we cannot perform atomic compound operations using a get/set style method call without using blocking synchronizers*.

If contention is the problem, I suggest reading [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-threads2/). A quick [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=reducing%20contention%20java&rlz=1C1MSIM_enUS572US572&oq=reducing%20contention%20java&aqs=chrome..69i57.4457j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) should turn up some other links if you are digging deeper.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of anything built in.

But you could use [`tryLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#tryLock--) to determine if you can acquire a `Lock` and perform a synchronized action or, if you cannot acquire the `Lock`, perform a non-synchronized action.

```
Lock l = ...

if(l.tryLock()) {
    try {
        // do your synchronized action
    } finally {
        l.unlock();
    }
} else {
    // welp, we couldn't get the lock.
    // do some local work.
}
```

Comment: Oops wrong lock ;-) Just had a major debate about that in another thread so I'm a little trigger-happy.

Comment: What happens when we cannot acquire the lock? Our code is not protected and we need to resort to some other action. I mentioned "semantics of `synchronized`," in saying that I will be guaranteed safety in execution, unless the code deadlocks, bad design creates inaccurate results, ect...

Comment: @xTrollxDudex Ah, I misunderstood the question. As your question now stands, I do not believe it is possible without CAS.

Comment: Thank you for your input. 2 answers now that say not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at lock-striping techniques (used in concurrenthashmap )to see if it meets your needs. Their basic idea is that you break your structure into segments and if a thread is modifying  one segment , you can still read from the other segments.

You can also try the CopyOnWriteArrayList  where if you are modfying an array, you create a copy and use it for any read operations while the array is being modified. The problem here is you are not guaranteed to get the latest update to the data

Both the above approaches are for building concurrent systems instead of synchronized systems.

Comment: Maybe I didn't clarify myself - I'm looking for an implementation of non-blocking locking that protect code blocks ie get/set invocations - not to avoid using the `synchronized` keyword.

Comment: @xTrollxDudex Concurrent systems are scalable versions of synchronized keywords. Both my approaches are still for protecting code blocks. However if you are looking for a single construct that will let you protect code while you can also call getter/setter on the same data, there is no construct

Comment: Now, we have a real answer: Not possible. Correct me if I am wrong.